# Красивое отображение графа локаций DS2

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, графы, networkx

Парсером собрал список локаций, нашел `networkx` для работы с графами, заполнил граф и отобразил его.

Мог бы и руками сделать, но это не интересно, поэтому подскажите как правильно сделать. Может другой библиотекой отрисовать граф или `<ваш_вариант>`.

Весь код:

```
global_transitions = {
    ("Железная Цитадель", "Мглистая Башня"),
    ("Шульва, Священный Город", "Святилище Дракона"),
    ("Огненная Башня Хейда", "Маджула"),
    ("Темнолесье", "Цитадель Алдии"),
    ("Цитадель Алдии", "Гнездо Дракона"),
    ("Замок Дранглик", "Трон Желания"),
    ("Роща Охотника", "Чистилище Нежити"),
    ("Шульва, Священный Город", "Пещера Мертвых"),
    ("Святилище Дракона", "Убежище Дракона"),
    ("Темнолесье", "Двери Фарроса"),
    ("Бухта Брайтстоун-Тселдора", "Личные Палаты Лорда"),
    ("Маджула", "Могила Святых"),
    ("Склеп Нежити", "Память Короля"),
    ("Мглистая Башня", "Железный Проход"),
    ("Железная Цитадель", "Башня Солнца"),
    ("Земляной Пик", "Железная Цитадель"),
    ("Роща Охотника", "Долина Жатвы"),
    ("Ледяная Элеум Лойс", "Храм Зимы"),
    ("Помойка", "Черная Расселина"),
    ("Бухта Брайтстоун-Тселдора", "Воспоминания Дракона"),
    ("Могила Святых", "Помойка"),
    ("Королевский Проход ", "Замок Дранглик"),
    ("Большой Собор", "Ледяная Элеум Лойс"),
    ("Маджула", "Роща Охотника"),
    ("Мглистая Башня", "Память Старого Железного Короля"),
    ("Безлюдная Пристань", "Огненная Башня Хейда"),
    ("Ледяная Элеум Лойс", "Холодные Окраины"),
    ("Храм Зимы", " Ледяная Элеум Лойс"),
    ("Гнездо Дракона", "Храм Дракона"),
    ("Большой Собор", "Предвечный Хаос"),
    ("Храм Аманы", "Склеп Нежити"),
    ("Долина Жатвы", "Земляной Пик"),
    ("Забытая Крепость", "Безлюдная Пристань"),
    ("Лес Павших Гигантов", "Память Ваммара"),
    (" Ледяная Элеум Лойс", "Большой Собор"),
    ("Черная Расселина", "Шульва, Священный Город"),
    ("Междумирье", "Маджула"),
    ("Замок Дранглик", "Королевский Проход"),
    ("Храм Зимы", "Замок Дранглик"),
    ("Маджула", "Помойка"),
    ("Лес Павших Гигантов", "Память Джейта"),
    ("Лес Павших Гигантов", "Забытая Крепость"),
    ("Огненная Башня Хейда", "Собор Лазурного Пути"),
    ("Лес Павших Гигантов", "Память Орро"),
    (" Ледяная Элеум Лойс", "Холодные Окраины"),
    ("Королевский Проход", "Храм Аманы"),
    ("Храм Аманы", "Королевский Проход "),
    ("Темнолесье", "Храм Зимы"),
    ("Маджула", "Темнолесье"),
    ("Маджула", "Лес Павших Гигантов"),
    ("Забытая Крепость", "Башня Луны"),
    ("Забытая Крепость", "Холм Грешников"),
    ("Двери Фарроса", "Бухта Брайтстоун-Тселдора"),
}

import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

for title, title_trans in global_transitions:
    G.add_edge(title, title_trans)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), width=6)

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=70)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='Verdana')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()  # display
```

А получилось вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я конечно с этой проблемой разобрался, но через js + html + D3.js, но хотелось бы решение на том языке, который мне нравится

Answer (score 0):

Решил приложить решение на `javascript`+`html`. [Из питоничьего тут генерация dataset для графика](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/a71ac993c3d81e774bdf8f00087dba2faf1fced2/graph__networkx__d3__dot_graphviz/js__d3)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force Layout with labels on edges</title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 1980;
    var h = 1000;
    var linkDistance = 50;

    var colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var dataset = {
        nodes: [{'name': 'Храм Зимы'}, {'name': 'Собор Лазурного Пути'}, {'name': 'Темнолесье'}, {'name': 'Память Орро'}, {'name': 'Башня Луны'}, {'name': 'Память Короля'}, {'name': 'Железный Проход'}, {'name': 'Мглистая Башня'}, {'name': 'Пещера Мертвых'}, {'name': 'Маджула'}, {'name': 'Чистилище Нежити'}, {'name': 'Предвечный Хаос'}, {'name': 'Склеп Нежити'}, {'name': 'Память Ваммара'}, {'name': 'Междумирье'}, {'name': 'Башня Солнца'}, {'name': 'Храм Аманы'}, {'name': 'Воспоминания Дракона'}, {'name': 'Безлюдная Пристань'}, {'name': 'Трон Желания'}, {'name': 'Роща Охотника'}, {'name': 'Замок Дранглик'}, {'name': 'Железная Цитадель'}, {'name': 'Забытая Крепость'}, {'name': 'Помойка'}, {'name': 'Бухта Брайтстоун-Тселдора'}, {'name': 'Земляной Пик'}, {'name': 'Черная Расселина'}, {'name': 'Лес Павших Гигантов'}, {'name': 'Цитадель Алдии'}, {'name': 'Долина Жатвы'}, {'name': 'Огненная Башня Хейда'}, {'name': 'Двери Фарроса'}, {'name': 'Королевский Проход'}, {'name': 'Гнездо Дракона'}, {'name': 'Убежище Дракона'}, {'name': 'Холм Грешников'}, {'name': 'Святилище Дракона'}, {'name': 'Королевский Проход '}, {'name': 'Храм Дракона'}, {'name': 'Память Старого Железного Короля'}, {'name': 'Холодные Окраины'}, {'name': 'Личные Палаты Лорда'}, {'name': 'Могила Святых'}, {'name': 'Шульва, Священный Город'}, {'name': 'Память Джейта'}, {'name': 'Большой Собор'}, {'name': ' Ледяная Элеум Лойс'}, {'name': 'Ледяная Элеум Лойс'}],
        edges: [{'source': 48, 'target': 0}, {'source': 28, 'target': 3}, {'source': 48, 'target': 41}, {'source': 47, 'target': 46}, {'source': 9, 'target': 2}, {'source': 21, 'target': 33}, {'source': 9, 'target': 20}, {'source': 9, 'target': 28}, {'source': 18, 'target': 31}, {'source': 47, 'target': 41}, {'source': 31, 'target': 9}, {'source': 2, 'target': 0}, {'source': 33, 'target': 16}, {'source': 46, 'target': 11}, {'source': 23, 'target': 4}, {'source': 20, 'target': 10}, {'source': 16, 'target': 12}, {'source': 14, 'target': 9}, {'source': 7, 'target': 40}, {'source': 38, 'target': 21}, {'source': 44, 'target': 37}, {'source': 21, 'target': 19}, {'source': 28, 'target': 13}, {'source': 0, 'target': 47}, {'source': 37, 'target': 35}, {'source': 22, 'target': 7}, {'source': 22, 'target': 15}, {'source': 29, 'target': 34}, {'source': 31, 'target': 1}, {'source': 32, 'target': 25}, {'source': 28, 'target': 23}, {'source': 2, 'target': 29}, {'source': 30, 'target': 26}, {'source': 25, 'target': 17}, {'source': 0, 'target': 21}, {'source': 28, 'target': 45}, {'source': 25, 'target': 42}, {'source': 43, 'target': 24}, {'source': 20, 'target': 30}, {'source': 9, 'target': 43}, {'source': 24, 'target': 27}, {'source': 16, 'target': 38}, {'source': 9, 'target': 24}, {'source': 46, 'target': 48}, {'source': 44, 'target': 8}, {'source': 27, 'target': 44}, {'source': 12, 'target': 5}, {'source': 2, 'target': 32}, {'source': 26, 'target': 22}, {'source': 34, 'target': 39}, {'source': 23, 'target': 18}, {'source': 7, 'target': 6}, {'source': 23, 'target': 36}]
    };
 
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({"width":w,"height":h});

    // nodes -- узлы графа
    // links -- связи графа
    // size  -- устанавливает доступный размер лейаута (ширину и высоту). В противном случае возвращает текущий размер, который по умолчанию равен [1, 1]
    // linkDistance -- расстояние между связанными узлами (длину связей)
    // charge  -- сила заряда узла
    // theta   -- устанавливает критерий аппроксимации Барнса-Хата
    // gravity -- устанавливает силу гравитационного притяжения
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(dataset.nodes)
        .links(dataset.edges)
        .size([w,h])
        .linkDistance([linkDistance])
        .charge([-500])
        .theta(0.1)
        .gravity(0.05)
        .start();

    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(dataset.edges)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("id",function(d,i) {return 'edge'+i})
      .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')
      .style("stroke","#ccc")
      .style("pointer-events", "none");
    
    var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr({"r":15})
      .style("fill",function(d,i){return colors(i);})
      .call(force.drag)

    var nodelabels = svg.selectAll(".nodelabel") 
       .data(dataset.nodes)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr({"x":function(d){return d.x;},
              "y":function(d){return d.y;},
              "class":"nodelabel",
              "stroke":"black"})
       .text(function(d){return d.name;});

    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(dataset.edges)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
               'class':'edgepath',
               'fill-opacity':0,
               'stroke-opacity':0,
               'fill':'blue',
               'stroke':'red',
               'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(dataset.edges)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr({'class':'edgelabel',
               'id':function(d,i){return 'edgelabel'+i},
               'dx':80,
               'dy':0,
               'font-size':10,
               'fill':'#aaa'});

/* Тут добавляются метки для ребер
    edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href',function(d,i) {return '#edgepath'+i})
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function(d,i){return 'label '+i});
*/

    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
        .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
               'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
               'refX':25,
               'refY':0,
               //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
               'orient':'auto',
               'markerWidth':10,
               'markerHeight':10,
               'xoverflow':'visible'})
        .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#ccc')
            .attr('stroke','#ccc');
     

    force.on("tick", function(){

        edges.attr({"x1": function(d){return d.source.x;},
                    "y1": function(d){return d.source.y;},
                    "x2": function(d){return d.target.x;},
                    "y2": function(d){return d.target.y;}
        });

        nodes.attr({"cx":function(d){return d.x;},
                    "cy":function(d){return d.y;}
        });

        nodelabels.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; }) 
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

        edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) { var path='M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y;
                                           //console.log(d)
                                           return path});       

        edgelabels.attr('transform',function(d,i){
            if (d.target.x<d.source.x){
                bbox = this.getBBox();
                rx = bbox.x+bbox.width/2;
                ry = bbox.y+bbox.height/2;
                return 'rotate(180 '+rx+' '+ry+')';
                }
            else {
                return 'rotate(0)';
                }
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]